# PHP gobal variable to differentiate between Users (login)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to write a Login-page for my friends. I want to have as the only one access to /root/root.php. The Login-Form and so on works fine, but the logged-in users could just enter the url to go into the root.php. How could I create a variable or something like this to block the access? Here is my code:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$hostname = 'localhost';
$dbname   = 'XXX';
$username = 'XXX';
$password = 'XXX';
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host isailed, perhaps the service is down!');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
$passWord=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, server FROM admins WHERE Name='$userName' AND  Password='$passWord'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$test =  mysql_fetch_row($query);


if ($rows==1)
{
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['Name'];
    if($test[1] == "Root") {
        header("Location: root/root.php");
    } else if($test[1] == "Minecraft"){
        header("Location: minecraft/minecraft.php");
    } else {
        echo "<center><h1>No database-entry!</h1></center>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<div class='login'>
            <table class='loginwindow'>
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>Wrong Password!</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='index.php'><button class='loginlogout'>To Login</button></a></td>
                </tr>
        </div>";
    //header("Location: login.html");
}?>
```

So, the root.php code is the following:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Root</title>
<?php
   session_start();

   if(!isset($_SESSION['userName']))
    {
        //exit(header("location: ../login.html"));
        echo "You need to login first!<br />";
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>To Login</a>";
        exit();
    }
?>

<link href="../style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['userName'];
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to get the User with the "root" entry in database to get access to the root.php. I tried, but it won't work.
Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also don't store password plain text. Please have a look at [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set a session variable `$_SESSION['root'] = $test[1];` below the line `$_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['Name'];` in **login.php** and then simply check `if($_SESSION['root'] == "Root")` in your **root.php**

**login.php**

```
$userName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Name']);
$passWord=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, server FROM admins WHERE Name='$userName' AND  Password='$passWord'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$test =  mysql_fetch_row($query);


if ($rows==1)
{
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $_POST['Name'];
    $_SESSION['root'] = $test[1]; // Add this line here
    if($test[1] == "Root") {
        header("Location: root/root.php");
    } else if($test[1] == "Minecraft"){
        header("Location: minecraft/minecraft.php");
    } else {
        echo "<center><h1>No database-entry!</h1></center>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<div class='login'>
            <table class='loginwindow'>
                <tr>
                    <td><h3>Wrong Password!</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href='index.php'><button class='loginlogout'>To Login</button></a></td>
                </tr>
        </div>";
    //header("Location: login.html");
}?>
```

**Root.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Root</title>
<?php
   session_start();

   if(!isset($_SESSION['userName']))
    {
        //exit(header("location: ../login.html"));
        echo "You need to login first!<br />";
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>To Login</a>";
        exit();
    }
    // Add below if condition
    if($_SESSION['root'] != "Root"){
        //exit(header("location: ../login.html"));
        echo "You are not allowed to access root!<br />";
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>To Login</a>";
        exit();
    }
?>

<link href="../style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['userName'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```